# Zeller's congruence gives the wrong outcome (Python)

Tags: python

So I want to calculate the day of the week by a given user input:

```
input1 =  int(input("Please enter the year in which you were born\n"))
input2 = int(input("Please enter the month in which you were born\n"))
input3 = int(input("Please enter the day on which you were born\n"))

if 1 <= input2 <= 2:
    input1 -= 1
elif input2 < 3:
    input2 = input2 + 10
else:
    input2 = input2 - 2
    
print(f'On which day of the week were you born?\n'
      f'Please input your answer of the day of the week as follows:\n'
      f'"mo", "tu", "we", "th", "fr", "sa", "su"')
inputweekday = str(input(f'Enter the day of the week on which you were born here\n'))

week_days=["su", "mo", "tu", "we", "th", "fr", "sa"]
D = abs(input1) % 100
C = int(str(input1)[:2])
A = 13*(input2 +1)
F = (input3 + (A//5) + D + (D//4) + (C//4) - 2*C) % 7

for i, x in enumerate(week_days):
    if F == i:
        F = x
        if F == inputweekday:
            print('You were correct.')
        else: 
            print(f'Your answer was not correct.')
            sys.exit(0)
```

I dont know why I cant seem to get the right days. Ive been struggling for hours and i couldnt find the answer online since almost all of them are implementented on C++.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
year =  int(input("Please enter the year in which you were born\n"))
month = int(input("Please enter the month in which you were born\n"))
day = int(input("Please enter the day on which you were born\n"))

if month < 3:
    month += 12
    year -= 1

    
# inputweekday = str(input(f'Enter the day of the week on which you were born here\n'))

week_days=["sat", "su", "mo", "tu", "we", "th", "fr"]
century = int(year / 100)
century_year = year % 100
weekday = (day + 13*(month + 1)//5 + century_year + century_year//4 + century//4 - 2*century) % 7
print(weekday)
print(week_days[weekday])
```

Comment: `year -= 1` means the year before: `In this algorithm January and February are counted as months 13 and 14 of the previous year. E.g. if it is 2 February 2010, the algorithm counts the date as the second day of the fourteenth month of 2009 (02/14/2009 in DD/MM/YYYY format)` from wikipedia.